How Does Signal Crest Factor Influence SNR and Effective Resolution in ADCs?
Recently, I've been looking into how crest factor of the signal affects the SQNR and i found what i think is an interesting relationship.
For example, take a signal in the range $[-V_p, V_p]$ and for $N$ bits the quantization step $q$ is,
$$ q = \frac{V_p-(-V_p)}{2^N} = \frac{2V_p}{2^N}$$
the crest factor of the signal is,
$$ CF = \frac{V_p}{V_{RMS}}$$
quantization noise power from Eq. 3 of MT-001.
$$P_q = \frac{q^2}{12}$$
Let the rms power of the signal be,
$$ P_{sig} = \left(\frac{V_p}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2 = V_{{RMS}}^2$$
the rms signal-to-noise ratio for an ideal $N$-bit converter is ,
$$ SNR = \frac{P_{sig}}{P_q}$$
$$ = \frac{P_{sig}}{\frac{q^2}{12}} = \frac{V_{RMS}^2}{\frac{4V_p^2}{2^{2N}12}} = 
\frac{2^{2N}3}{\left(\frac{V_p}{V_{RMS}} \right)^2} = \frac{2^{2N}3}{CF^2}$$
$$ = 10 \log_{10} \left(2^{2N} \right) + 10 \log_{10} \left(\frac{3}{CF^2} \right)$$
$$ \boxed{= 6.02N+10 \log_{10} \left(\frac{3}{CF^2} \right)}$$
Assuming my math is right, why don't i see this formula for SNR?, everywhere i go, SNR is approximated as $6.02N+1.76$ for an ideal quantizer with full-scale sinewave input. The same equation can be derived if i substitute $CF$ as $1.414$ (crest factor of sine wave).
If i want to estimate SNR for a non-sinusoidal signal, for instance, an OFDM signal and according to the wiki, its $CF$ is $4$. So, for a 14-bit ENOB converter, the SNR is,
$$ SNR = 6.02\times 14 +10 \log_{10} \left(\frac{3}{4^2} \right) = 77.01 \text{dB}$$
in the datasheet, the SNR is calculated based on a single tone test,
$$ SNR = 6.02\times 14 + 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{3}{1.414^2} \right) = 6.02\times 14 + 1.76 = 86.04 \text{dB} $$
This is the confusing part, if the SNR is based on the $CF$ of the signal for a given ENOB, is it right to say the ENOB remains the same?. Like in the above example, for two different signals i get two different SNR ($77.01 \text{dB}$ and $86.04 \text{dB}$) for the same 14-bits. From what i understand, for every $\approx 6 \text{dB}$ rise in SNR, you get 1-bit increase in resolution (that's why oversampling is effective right?) and the inverse is also true. By this statement,
How much bits did i lose\gain for the OFDM signal?
How to calculate it?
What is the reference value that is used to determine whether or not the SNR gained\lost $x \text{dB}$, and why that ref value?

The dependency of the SNR on the crest factor is certainly well known. In fact, Crest factor reduction is a big part of the  process called  "mastering" in audio . Keep in mind that this particular consideration is only relevant if the quantization noise is indeed a significant part of the overall noise. In many communication scenarios the channel noise is the main problem.

i wanted to know how crest factor influences A2D conversion but i couldn't find much info about it. Almost all of it were related to audio and power electronics, it doesn't have much impact in A2D?

Crest factor has a lot of impact on A/D conversion. As you (correctly) deduced it directly determines the signal noise ratio. In practice this means that trade off head room (or occasional clipping) against the noise floor (which may be determined by the quantization noise or analog noise in your system)

I think your math is right but your understanding of it is wrong. The noise you consider is quantization noise, which is indifferent to the signal, but obviously  the signal’s power depends on the signal you consider right? So the measured SNR will depend on it as well.
As a toy example, if you use low transmission power, such that the maximal value of the signal spans only half of the ADC full scale, the ADC enob remains unchanged, but the higher bits will zero, and the usable dynamic range, and effective SNR when you do processing is limited further, as your signal is closer to your he noise floor.
Lastly, the actual measured SNR will be worse, since you only consider quantization noise and ignore the self noise of the ADC.

That makes so much sense. ENOB of an ADC is a measure of the quantization noise floor including other error sources of the ADC, so, it is indifferent of the input signal. Even though i know of this, i don't know why i thought the noise floor will raise. So, for a full-scale sine wave, if the peak is at 0dB then OFDM peak will be around $77.01-86.04 = -9.03 \text{dB}$?. Its the signal that goes down, the ENOB of the ADC remains the same but the number of bits that contains the information will be reduced, in this case 1.5-bits will be zero/useless.

Sounds you got it right

About the higher bits being zero, i don't think it is right. If the OFDM is full-scale i would get SQNR of 77.01dB and the higher bits of the ADC (in this case - 1.2 bits) will account for the peaks. If i have a sine wave of 77.01dB SQNR, then the higher 1.2 bits will be zero and i can increase the power by 9dB without worrying about clipping. If do the same with OFDM, the signal will go beyond the range of the ADC and it will clip. Discarding higher-bits will also leads to clipping.

The higher bits being zero is true in the toy example I gave, not necessarily for any signal.

For a general signal though the relation of peak value to signal energy (or RMS value), is still line shape dependent of course.

I have detailed this very question specific to OFDM and any other Gaussian distributed waveform as summarized in the following graphic:

The number of bits shown is the Effective Number of Bits, or ENOB which includes all noise sources as contributed by the ADC and estimated as a white noise source (uniform PSD from $-f_s/2$ to $+f_s/2$. Ultimately their should be sufficient gain ahead of the ADC so that the quantization noise is not degrading our sensitivity, but by having the SNR of the ADC we can then make the optimum trade between minimizing degradation to receiver sensitivity (noise figure) and providing maximum dynamic range for processing stronger signals and interference in the subsequent digital processing. This is an important consideration in the overall design of the receiver for both of these metrics, and having the ADC SNR provides a quantifiable result for doing that (just as we want quantified metrics for the noise contributions of every other component in the receiver).
The horizontal axis represents the rms level of the waveform at the input to the ADC relative to the DC full scale level (a full scale sine wave is therefore -3 dBFS on this axis). The linear lines to the left of the plot is the familiar SNR = 6.02 dB/bit + 1.76 dB predicting the SNR for a full scale sine wave relative to the quantization noise level. The curve on the right that all the curves approach is the clipping noise as predicted by the tail of a Gaussian distribution (OFDM is very well approximated as a Gaussian distribution due to the central limit theorem with the associated addition of multiple independent sub-carriers). A similar curve can be created for alternate distributions of other waveform types.
The SNR compared to a sine wave is just to create a reproduceable metric with a reference level, as the quantization noise that is thus created is then generally independent of the waveform level as long as no clipping occurs. A sine wave has a 3 dB peak-avg ratio, and thus when set at -3 dBFS, no clipping occurs. However other waveforms such as OFDM have a much larger peak to average ratio, and therefore their rms levels must be set to lower levels to minimize the effects of clipping. This curves suggests the optimum set-point for those cases.
As an example use of the curve, consider using an ADC that has an ENOB of 10 bits (as given by the ADC data sheet for the users operating conditions, or as determined by test with a full scale sine wave whose frequency is not a sub-multiple of the sampling clock). From my chart, the minimum noise occurs with a level of -14 dBFS (DC) or -11 dB relative to a full scale sine wave. From that I would translate from my circuit the rms voltage level where the full scale sinewave is at the threshold of clipping, drop that rms level by 11 dB and use that as the set-point for the level of my waveform at the ADC input (as set by an AGC).
See these related post which details this further:
ADC quantization +thermal noise
How to adjust receiver gains to avoid saturation and quantization noise to optimise post digital processing?
Choosing the scaling parameters for a modem implementation
Simulating ADC Effects on DSP Algorithm with Fixed-Point Representation
If there is any question of OFDM being Gaussian distributed, please see DSP.SE #86868 comparing the PAPR for OFDM waveforms to Gaussian test signals. However, if crest factor reduction is employed, that will change these statistics and shift the clipping noise curve as used to the right accordingly.
I go into much deeper details of this and other considerations for practical ADC's in a software radio in my upcoming course "DSP for Software Radio" kicking off next week with the early registration discount ending today! More details and to sign up here: https://dsprelated.com/courses

I believe I have a good grasp of it now. To confirm, I replicated your graph for my signal, and it matched exactly what I expected. With this, along with the answers to my previous questions, I think I’m ready to proceed with what I want to do.

good news! Thanks for letting me know. I see now that I already gave you this graph and explanation to a prior question of yours. I hope it helped specific to this question here as this is how I would consider the effect of crest factor and specifically for OFDM.
